# Twitter Search Api 1.1 searching by date

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

Since Twitter Search Api 1.1 does not have since parameter to specify the start date, how do I get the tweets between 2 different dates(within 7 days limit)?

Note: I cannot use the `since_id` and `max_id` as parameters because I have only 2 dates and search query as inputs.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct way of doing it, but here are couple of ideas. You have a `from` date and a `to` date, right? So -

1. Set `result_type` to `recent` and `until` to your `to` date and `count` to 100.
2. from the result of 1, you get 100 tweets and you check if you've hit the `from` date, if not keep going till you reach `from` date using the `max_id` parameter.

Another idea would be -

1. Set `result_type` to `recent` and `until` to your `from` date. get the ID of the latest tweet from there. You need all the tweets since that ID till your `to` date ends.
2. So you set `since_id` to that ID you got in step 1 and keep requesting and updating `since_id` after each request till you hit your `to` date's end.

Comment: I have though of this , but since / until is not getting the expected results at all .. especially rolling back to 2011 ... and i am getting results for profile created_at date instead of status .